# Cypher query for user in a group but not in another

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to create a seemingly simple query, but I'm not able to get the final result.
I have a dump of my directory in Neo4j. I want to find all users that are part of a group with a name that contains *XYZ* and are **NOT** part of any group containing *ABC*.
This is what I created so far:

```
MATCH p=shortestPath((u:User)-[r:MemberOf]->(g:Group))  WHERE g.name contains 'XYZ' AND not g.name  contains 'ABC' RETURN u.name,g.name
```

Of course this does not work. The first part is ok, user in a group with XYZ in it, the second is not.
Can someone help me here? Thanks
Thanks

Comment: The two answers below give me different results and none of them are correct.
I suppose this is due to the naming of the groups that partially collide and the *contains* part works badly.
To be more precise: all my interesting groups are in the form:
*GRP-VPN-A*, *GRP-VPN-B*, and so on.
-VPN- was what I was referring with XYZ.
Special groups are *-VPN-SPECIAL-*   
-VPN-SPECIAL- is what I was referring to with ABC.
So I suppose the -VPN- part that is common to both creates some problem here, but can't find it. Queries below return 450 items one and 600 the other, the correct answer is 5.

Comment: To be more specific (damn edit limits...):
Al groups have the form GRP-VPN-* with * being the specific VPN group.
There are some special groups with the naming GRP-VPN-SPECIALWORD*.
So I can identify those special groups with substring or regex, the base GRP-VPN-* is common.
I want to find user Alice that is in GRP-VPN-Engineering and NOT in GRP-VPN-Special

Comment: Rationale is that if you are in a GRP-VPN-* group you must also be in a GRP-VPN-SPECIAL* one. You may not belong to a GRP-VPN- group, in which case you do not need a GRP-VPN-SPECIAL too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple NOT EXISTS {} subquery will do the trick here, you'll need Neo4j 4.x for this:

```
MATCH p=shortestPath((u:User)-[r:MemberOf]->(g:Group))  
WHERE g.name contains 'XYZ' AND NOT EXISTS {
  MATCH (u)-[:MemberOf]->(exclude:Group)
  WHERE exclude.name CONTAINS 'ABC'
}
RETURN u.name, g.name
```

Be aware that with shortestPath queries, both endnodes will be found before the expansion of the path between them, so your query will generate a number of rows from the cross product of all :Group nodes starting with 'XYZ', and all :User nodes that aren't a part of an 'ABC' group, then it will look for the shortest path between all rows from that cross product result. That doesn't sound efficient, so you might want to rethink your shortestPath() approach.

Comment: I do have 4.x and the query runs, but see my comments in the original post about the naming, I think this is the problem. Trying some regexes here.

Comment: About the shortestPath: I'm not fluent with cypher, so this is what I came to looking at some examples. What I meant is "user is part of a group".
Even if efficiency is not a problem here since the query is batch and run once a day, I would like to learn the right way to do it.  Just removing the shortestPath part made the query waaaay faster (and still wrong, but that is another path). Thanks

Comment: Almost there. This approach seems correct, I'm just polishing my regex-fu to correctly match the names and using some ToUpper() since I have weird casing around...

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this approach:

```
MATCH p=shortestPath((u:User)-[r:MemberOf]->(g:Group))  
WHERE g.name contains 'XYZ' 
AND SIZE(
      [gName IN [(u)-[:MemberOf]->(g:Group) | g.name] WHERE gName CONTAINS 'ABC'])=0
RETURN u.name,g.name
```

Second try, only retuning the users, as requested in the OP. IMHO there is no need for a shortestPath.

```
WITH 'XYZ' AS includeString, 'ABC' AS excludeString
MATCH (u:User)
WHERE ANY(groupName IN [(u)-[:MemberOf]->(g:Group) | g.name] WHERE groupName CONTAINS includeString)
      AND
      NONE(groupName IN [(u)-[:MemberOf]->(g:Group) | g.name] WHERE groupName CONTAINS excludeString)
RETURN u.name
```

Comment: Thank you @graphileon but this is not working, see my update comment above

Comment: I gave it a second try ..

Comment: I started from the query from @InverseFalcon below and worked out the regexes needed to obtain my result. Those were the main problem. Applying the same regexes to your query instead of the CONTAINS leads to the same result, so thank you for your help. I just prefer the InverseFalcon solution as it is easier/natural for me to understand. Without the ShortestPath both execute in a fraction of a second

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to both the user above I mixed the queries and got the result:

```
WITH 'incl-regex' AS includeString, 'excl-regex' AS excludeString
MATCH p=(u:User)-[r:MemberOf]->(g:Group)  
WHERE toupper(g.name) =~ includeString AND NOT EXISTS {
  MATCH (u)-[:MemberOf]->(exclude:Group)
  WHERE toupper(exclude.name) =~ excludeString
}
RETURN u.name, g.name
```

This is both fast (no shortestPath) and accurate. I find @InverseFalcon version easier to understand as it reads just like I was thinking to implement "give me users in groups like this and not like that".
I needed some regex tweaking as groups name are pretty complex.

Comment: you may loose the p=    you don't need a path

Comment: Thank you also for this tip, actually I do not need p